# Error al buscar una palabra en un string

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de aplicar estilo con `js` si en la `url` aparece la palabra ***pedido*** de la siguiente forma:

El error que aparece en `consola`

**Uncaught TypeError: paginaCarrito.search is not a function**

```js
var paginaCarrito = window.location;

var buscarCarrito = paginaCarrito.search("pedido");
console.log(buscarCarrito);

setTimeout(function() {



if (buscarCarrito != "-1"){

  var menuCarrito = document.getElementById('leo-verticalmenu');
  menuCarrito.classList.remove("active");

  document.getElementById('left_column').style.display='none';

}}, 3000);
```

Comment: Que te devuelve paginaCarrito?

Comment: no me devuelve nada en consola

Comment: Por eso el error, por qué esa variable debería tener por ejemplo una cadena de texto

Comment: He creado la `var` al principio y ahora si que está definida, pero me sigue dando el mismo error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo he resuelto de la siguiente manera, `windows.location` devuleve muchos parametros a mi parecer, pero lo que necesito es la `url` solamente, asi que he cambiado a `window.location.href`

```js
var paginaCarrito = window.location.href;

var buscarCarrito = paginaCarrito.search("pedido");
console.log(buscarCarrito);

setTimeout(function() {

if (buscarCarrito != "-1"){

  var menuCarrito = document.getElementById('leo-verticalmenu');
  menuCarrito.classList.remove("active");

  document.getElementById('left_column').style.display='none';

}}, 800);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que sucede que paginaCarrito.search("pedido") no es una funcion sino que retorna un string en el cual ya puedes hacer la busqueda

```js
var paginaCarrito = window.location;    


setTimeout(function() {

var buscarCarrito = paginaCarrito.search;
 var control =false:
if(buscarCarrito .includes('pedido')){
 control= true; // incluye la palabra pedido
}

if (buscarCarrito != false){

  var menuCarrito = document.getElementById('leo-verticalmenu');
  menuCarrito.classList.remove("active");

  document.getElementById('left_column').style.display='none';

}}, 3000);
```

adjunto mi idea de como puedes verificar si contiene la palabra pedido